# ROS Answers SE migration: rosinstall

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what is rosinstall ? how can i install it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155856/rosinstall/) by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you know,  the answer for your question is described on this page ( http://wiki.ros.org/fuerte/Installation/Overlays ).

```
rosws init ~/fuerte_workspace /opt/ros/fuerte
```

This command **creates** the files setup.bash, setup.sh, setup.zsh and the hidden file **.rosinstall** in the directory ~/fuerte_workspace.
I also answered your question on this page( http://answers.ros.org/question/155786/install-face_recognition-pakage/ ). Didn't you look at it?

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on 2014-04-22**:
I try to execute your answer but  still appear that """ImportError: No module named six
"""!!!

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-22**:
The problem is solved on your page ( http://answers.ros.org/question/155841/creating-a-new-overlay/ ). Thanks, @ahendrix!